How to detect which line of code has modified the global variable (not debug mode)
Development environment: STM32F417ZG/keil uvision 5/FreeRTOS
Problem description: During the normal working phase of my product, a global variable is suddenly found to have been modified accidentally. This variable was not modified by my normal code as there is only one place where the normal code is modified and I am sure enough it doesn't get triggered. So it could have been caused by a memory stepping, thread safety or some other exception.
This is a very low probability problem, so it is difficult to reproduce the problem in keil's debug mode and use data breakpoint to locate the problematic code that modified this global variable.
My question is: how can I locate which line in my project's source code caused the global variable to be modified during the normal working phase of the product.
Does anyone have any good ideas on how to do this?

First thing that comes to mind is watch point, which require debug mode. If your hardware supports hardware watchpoints the program shouldnt be slowed by it much.

A common reason is an out of bounds access for some array "close" to the changing variable. I would start by looking into that.

There is one way a "properly ordered" deck of cards can be arranged. The number of ways the same deck can be "disordered" is astronomical. Suggest you start "turning off" functionality (comment-out sections of code), then test-Test-TEST... This sort of problem crops up too often when racing toward completion overlooks a seemingly innocuous flaw in coding (or design). Only you can track down the bug. Learn from this experience. (I once spent two days trying to find what turned out to be an "errant" semi-colon... Happens...)

@Fe2O3 Does my question have something to do with "disordered"? I don't understand quite well. Could you give me more details or example?

My goal is to locate the code line number that modifies the global variable. So it's crucial to notify me as long as the variable is modified.
I am not quite sure whether the following way is good:
As I am using STM32F417ZG that has MPU, it's possible to configure MPU to monitor the modified memory.
Once it's modified, a function like Memory_Fault_Handler() would be called. Inside the function some useful details including task-id can be set.

Watch this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qybUFnY7Y8w] Would this one-shot sequence have run from beginning to end if the staff had not been meticulous in testing each component separately and in conjunction with others? So it is with programming. Unrecognised defects in "order" come back to bite (often mere hours before the project would be completed/demonstrated.) Backtrack the development until you discover the flaw... and hope that there's only one problem to be found & fixed.
